# Problema na chegada da informação pelo AJAX

Tags: ajax

Estou com o problema na requisição do ajax. Eu consigo enviar a informação, mas quando chega na outra página aparece a mensagem

> [object HTMLInputElement]

Não consigo entender. Ele enviou um objeto?

```
// função que recebe o evento do javascript onkeyup
function verificaEmail(x){
            var conectarServidor = iniciarAjax();
            if (conectarServidor) {
                conectarServidor.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (conectarServidor.readyState == 4) {
                        if (conectarServidor.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("comparaEmail").innerHTML = this.responseText;

                    }   else {
                            alert("O sistema não está funcionando corretamente! ");
                        }
                    }
                }
                conectarServidor.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/locadora/cadastro.php?q="+email,true);
                conectarServidor.send();
            }
        }   
// até aqui tudo bem. Mas quando chega na outra página aparece essa mensagem.

    $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","locadora");
        $email = $_REQUEST["q"];
        $sql = "select*from cliente where email='email'";
        $rs = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
         // abaixo eu fiz uma condição para saber se exite o email.
         // aquela mensagem só apareceria se eu escrevesse echo $email.
        if($result >="1"){
           echo "usuário já cadastrado."
        }
        else{
         echo "";
           }
```

Comment: *"Ele enviou um objeto?"* - Sim, `HTMLInputElement` é um objeto que representa o campo `<input>` do formulário. Você pode obter informações deste objeto acessando suas propriedades: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

Comment: Consegui resolver. Muito obrigado.O problema era no parâmetro da função. Na tag input eu coloquei uma função com o evento onkeyup. Só que na hora, não enviava nada. Por isso aparecia esse problema. Eu tinha ter que colocado this.value. Ex onkeyup=verificaEmail(this.value);